# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize issue

Tags: c#, json

Trying to deserialize json from a web api. Here is the incoming json:

```
{"0":{"productname":"France and the French",
"imageurl":"http://img.rakuten.com/PIC/32994457/0/1/250/32994457.jpg",
"producturl":"http://www.theurl.com/rd.aspx?3d",
"price":"19.51",
"currency":"USD",
"saleprice":"",
"storename":"Buy.com (dba Rakuten.com Shopping)"}
}
```

Here is my data class:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("productname")]
    public string productname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("imageurl")]
    public string imageurl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("producturl")]
    public string producturl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public string price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string currency { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("saleprice")]
    public string saleprice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("storename")]
    public string storename { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code:

```
string json = upcclient.GetProductJSON(upc, accessToken);
Product myproduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

Should be pretty straight forward. json is getting populated, but no matter what I try - Product as an list of products in a master data class, array of product, etc, myproduct is never populated.

Thanks for the help in advance. This stuff isn't usually this hard. I've done it 50 times or so, but this time is getting to me.

Comment: The key might be at the beginning, with `{"0":`

Comment: You appear to know the answer to your own question.. but you're over thinking it. `Product as an list of products in a master data class, array of product` - correct. Its an array. Deserialize it as one.

Comment: Technically a JSON array should be inside square brackets {"0":[ {data here} ]}. IN this instance, it is not. I am getting it from the provider at a JSON array inside curly brackets and only ever one item. I tried the following just now, but no go

    List<Product> p = (List<Product>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(List<Product>));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example JSON you posted, `Product` is an object contained within the `0` field of a root object, and the root object doesn't appear to be using JSON array syntax. Unfortunately, this is fairly ugly to elegantly map to a C# class if you expect to get an arbitrary number of results. If you know you're only going to get one product, you can simply add a root class:

```
public class ProductWrapper
{
  [JsonProperty("0")]
  public Product Product
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

and do:

```
string json = upcclient.GetProductJSON(upc, accessToken);
Product myproduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductWrapper>(json).Product;
```

I suspect this API is designed to potentially return multiple products, though, so this may not be what you're looking for. If this is an API you have control over, it may be worth requesting that the JSON actually returns an **array** of products, rather than the object that it returns now.

Comment: They were right above, I was overthinking it. Your solution works correctly (assuming Product is changed to ProductWrapper). Thanks. I just got into my hear that the JSON was wrong when it was just be all the time.